# How to avoid name collisions in python decorators functions

Tags: python, python-decorators, name-collision

I would like to write a python decorator so that a function raising an exception will be run again until either it succeeds, or it reaches the maximum number of attempts before giving up.

Like so :

```
def tryagain(func):
    def retrier(*args,**kwargs,attempts=MAXIMUM):
        try:
            return func(*args,**kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            if numberofattempts > 0:
                logging.error("Failed. Trying again")
                return retrier(*args,**kwargs,attempts=attempts-1)
            else:
                logging.error("Tried %d times and failed, giving up" % MAXIMUM)
                raise e
    return retrier
```

My problem is that I want a guarantee that no matter what names the kwargs contain, there cannot be a collision with the name used to denote the number of attempts made.

however this does not work when the function itself takes `attempts` as a keyword argument

```
@tryagain
def other(a,b,attempts=c):
    ...
    raise Exception

other(x,y,attempts=z)
```

In this example,if other is run, it will run z times and not MAXIMUM times (note that for this bug to happen, the keyword argument must be explicitly used in the call !).

Comment: If you are going to add an argument to the decorated function, then you have to document the name used and the fact that you cannot decorate a function that already uses an argument by that name.

Comment: are you asking what happens if attempts is one of the kwargs named for your function?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes, precisely !

Comment: Also, don't use recursion for this; it just eats up stack space unnecessarily. Use a loop instead.

Comment: Can you provide a call that goes wrong? And ideally actual minimal code, not something convoluted.

Comment: @StefanPochmann As long as you won't be decorating methods, that's probably safe. If you do, though, then you have to adjust whether the positional argument used by `retrier` is the first or second as appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify decorator parameter, something along the lines of this:

```
import logging

MAXIMUM = 5

def tryagain(attempts=MAXIMUM):
    def __retrier(func):
        def retrier(*args,**kwargs):
            nonlocal attempts
            while True:
                try:
                    return func(*args,**kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    attempts -= 1
                    if attempts > 0:
                        print('Failed, attempts left=', attempts)
                        continue
                    else:
                        print('Giving up')
                        raise
        return retrier
    return __retrier


@tryagain(5)                              # <-- this specifies number of attempts
def fun(attempts='This is my parameter'): # <-- here the function specifies its own `attempts` parameter, unrelated to decorator
    raise Exception(attempts)

fun()
```

Comment: This also effectively hard-codes the number of attempts into the new function, rather than being something you can specify at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an argument, get the number of retry attempts from a function attribute.

```
def tryagain(func):
    def retrier(*args,**kwargs):
        retries = getattr(func, "attempts", MAXIMUM)
        while retries + 1 > 0:
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error("Failed. Trying again")
                last_exception = e
            retries -= 1
        else:
            logging.error("Tried %d times and failed, giving up", retries)
            raise last_exception

    return retrier

@tryagain
def my_func(...):
    ...

my_func.attempts = 10
my_func()  # Will try it 10 times
```

To make `MAXIMUM` something you can specify when you call decorate the function, change the definition to

```
def tryagain(maximum=10):
    def _(f):
        def retrier(*args, **kwargs):
            retries = getattr(func, "attempts", maximum)
            while retries + 1 > 0:
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error("Failed. Trying again")
                    last_exception = e
                retries -= 1
            else:
                logging.error("Tried %d times and failed, giving up", retries)
                raise last_exception
        return retrier
    return _
```

Although there's still a risk of a name collision with the `attempts` attributes, the fact that function attributes are rarely used makes it more reasonable to document `tryagain` as not working with functions with a pre-existing `attempts` attribute.

(I leave it as an exercise to modify `tryagain` to take an attribute name to use as an argument:

```
@tryagain(15, 'max_retries')
def my_func(...):
    ...
```

so that you can choose an unused name at decoration time. For that matter, you can also use an argument to `tryagain` as the name of a keyword argument to add to `my_func`.)